# Pass parameters via GET to return filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to return a data query via GET to return me values according to what is selected in the v-model.
I would like to know how to get the v-model values from the input and make the request to get by parameter

My filter (the components are already returning object as your id according to what I select)

```
  <div class="row gutter-sm">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <q-card class="full-width bg-white q-pa-md q-card-flex">
            <div class="col-md-2">            
              <situacao-select multiple v-model="situacao" :stackLabel="'Situação OS'" style="height:50px;" :clearable="true" />            
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input-holder label="Help Desk" style="height:50px;">
                  <pessoa-funcao-select :funcao="'Help Desk'" :clearable="true" />
              </input-holder>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input-holder label="Supervisor" style="height:50px;">
                  <pessoa-funcao-select :funcao="'Supervisor'" :clearable="true" />
              </input-holder>
            </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <q-btn
                      color="primary"
                      style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
                      @click="search = false"
                    >FILTER</q-btn>
                </div>                                        
            </div>                   
       </q-card>
```

Request the API (I know it is wrong, I would like to know how to request with the parameter according to what the GET requests)

```
     mounted() {
        this.refresh()
 },
 methods: {
      refresh () {
         this.$axios.get()
         
          this.$axios.get("/Operacional/GetRelatorio").then(res => { 
            this.prazos = res.data
            this.$refs.chart1.updateSeries([{
                name: 'NO PRAZO',
                data: [this.prazos.noPrazo, this.prazos.emDia, this.prazos.atrasadas]
             }])
          })
          this.$axios.get("/Operacional/GetAprovadas").then(res => {
            this.os = res.data
          })
          this.$axios.get("/Operacional/GetPendenciasOS").then(res => {
            this.os = res.data
            this.$refs.chart4.updateSeries([{
                name: 'EM DIA',
                data: [ this.os.emdiaPendencia, this.os.emdiaSPendencia],
              },{
                name: 'ATRASADAS',
                data: [ this.os.atrasadasPendencia, this.os.atrasadasSPendencia],
                }
             ])
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get that value you selected, let's say you want to use 'situacao'.
and pass that value to your backend via GET parameters:

```
refresh () {
         this.$axios.get()
    
         var selectedSituacao = this.situacao;
         var url = "/Operacional/GetRelatorio?ID=" + selectedSituacao;

         this.$axios.get(url).then(res => { .... })

         // or you could do this:
         var axiosParams = {
             params: {
                ID: selectedSituacao
             }
         }
         this.$axios.get("/Operacional/GetRelatorio", axiosParams).then(res => { .... })
```

edit: Updated url get parameter situacao to ID as requested.

Comment: In this case the parameter I want to take is the ID. Would I have to make one of these for each model or is there a method to do it for everyone?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to supply ID as a GET parameters or do you want to use id from your vue instance?

Comment: ID as GET parameter

Comment: i've updated the example to reflect how you would pass the selected value as `id`

Comment: no need to add  "+ qs.stringify " right after the url? Another thing, when I declare "this.situacao" am I having access to the v-model of that component already?

Comment: yes that is an option to encode it properly. I would make it work first and then add the encoding once you have seen that it works. If you go the route with the axiosParams then axios will automatically encode it for you.

Comment: the error came out, thank u, now my doubt is: only if I declare "this.situation" does it have access to the situation component that comes from another place?

Comment: If there is another component responsible for `this.situation` that component should communicate with this component (this component is responsible for getting the relevant data based on situation from the server). This is the topic of component communication (passing data via props and receiving and reacting to events emitted by components) in Vue.

Comment: show, then I declare the component data on the data() that the parameter will be sent, so I understood

Comment: Hello Christian, I could show you but without further context chances are that it will be very confusing for you. I'd recommend you investigate the topic first (vue component communication) and ask us if you encounter any problems. As for the question you originally asked, has that been sufficiently answered?